# How to access storage file using database query in LARAVEL

Tags: php, database, laravel, image, url

I am working with laravel project and facing a problem.
I created a database model called "Product" which have a field called "product_image" and its data type is string.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('product_image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

By using controller,I did enable uploading product image and product model capable to get that files active name with its extension,even I am able to find that uploaded file on `storage/app/example.jpg`.

```
$file = $request->file('product_image');
        $filename = 'product_image-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $file->storeAs('product-image', $filename);
        $product->product_image = $path ;
```

But when I am running a @foreach loop on my blade template and trying to fetch image over this.

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
<tr>
<td>{{$p->product_title}}</td>
<td><img src="/storage/app/product-image/{{$p->product_image}}" alt="" style="height:80px; width:80px"/></td>
@endforeach
```

I am founding nothing and image field is still showing without original image :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTYzJ.jpg)

I find out the problem but do not know the solution and lost in the dark.
The actual problem is in, `<img src="`/storage/app/product-image/{{$p->product_image}}`" alt="" style="height:80px; width:80px"/>`

because its not founding the url for that image.

My question is, how we can provide URL for that particular image using for loop which will be able to locate that image from storage/app/example directory.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been tried using artisan command for creating the symbolic link to the public files as describe [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

run    `php artisan storage:link`

In your *`config/filesystems.php`* change into something like this:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/product_image',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
   ],
```

Then access your file like this in your blade template:

```
<img src="{{ asset('product_image/'. $p->product_image) }}" alt="" style="height:80px; width:80px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the image in your browser like - http://urdomain.com/storage/app/product-image/example.jpg ?

In your question you have mentioned storage/app/example.jpg but while accessing in your template you are referring it as storage/app/product-image/example.jpg. The path would be the problem?

Your loop looks like OK. IMO.

Comment: See the path, its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using Vagrant or Laradock you should run your command `php artisan storage:link` inside your workspace, otherwise it won't work and will result to 404 when accessing it within your browser.